# Are linux notifications logged somewhere?

Tags: linux, debian, notifications, xfce

I sometimes get a notification in the corner of the screen and don't have/take the time to read it before it disappears. That shouldn't be a major issue in general, since major issues *should* be reported by some other means, and often it's an email or a message in some app that I find there later, but sometimes it's a little irritating not to know what was that message there just before I looked.

Is there some way to have access to a log of notifications? I'm a debian xfce user, but of course the more general a solution would exist, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have a text file named `$HOME/.cache/xfce4/notifyd/log.`
I'm on Arch, and it may not be exactly the same on Debian, but xfce4-notifyd should have a log around there somewhere :-)

The file is quite readable:

```
[time stamp]
app_name=something
summary=text
body=more text
app_icon=icon name
expire-timeout=time to show notification
```

Comment: Thx, I've added details of what I found out following your message.

Comment: as of [0.8.0 (from 2023-02-10)](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-notifyd/blob/master/NEWS) the file is now `log.sqlite`